# When burninating, what should I do with an unclear question that only has one tag (the one I'm burninating)?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

I was working my way through the [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header) tag and came across [this](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dhnNaKQ_6NoJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/23811165/how-do-i-name-the-header+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) post. Now unfortunately the post is too broad to determine other possible tags that could be used to replace it's current one, so besides flagging (which I've already done) how else could this post be handled (and others of this sort)?

Comment: it is too broad, so need to be closed. and deleted. and tag go with it.

Comment: @BryanChen I've already flagged it. I was just wondering if there was anything I could do while I'm waiting it to get deleted (if it does).

Comment: I'd retag that, but I don't even know what it's about. If the OP doesn't come back and edit before the question goes from "on hold" to "closed", flag it again and we can delete it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Exactly, I can't even figure out what language that is. So when I reflag it should I use a custom flag?

Comment: Yes, just flag it as "other" and explain that the question is holding us up from getting rid of a bad tag.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Right ok. Should I take this course of action for all posts that are like this, or is this only a "once-off" thing?

Comment: Actually, they haven't been seen since June 6th, so I'm just going to delete it. I'll write up an answer with general guidelines.

Comment: (I usually just switch the tag to language-agnostic, but that isn't the best solution)

Comment: Come to think of it, if you want to see it destroyed within a minute, just tag it PHP or C++ or both (hueh hueh)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under normal circumstances I'd say to just flag it for deletion, but this question isn't even closed yet. Ironically, it probably fell through the cracks due to bad tagging.

Normally, if the OP was active, I'd let the question go through the normal close/delete process so that the OP had a fair chance to fix the question.  Since the OP in this specific case hasn't been seen in over three weeks, I just deleted the question so it doesn't hold up a tag burnination for an additional five days as it goes from "on hold" to "closed."

Comment: So when you say, "flag it for deletion", do you mean raise an "other" flag and explain what's going on?

Comment: @Sam Yes. If you have enough reputation to vote for deletion, you can do that too, but an "other" flag might be quicker.

Comment: Ok. When I do get the rep for voting to delete, It's alright to raise a custom flag + vote to delete? I would have thought VtD would have sufficed.

Comment: @Sam For most posts a vote to delete would be enough. When it's a special case like this, it's ok to do both.